# Proving the martingale property for a finite number of past times

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

The exercise is from  Yuh-Dauh Lyuu's *Financial Engineering and Computation: Principles, Mathematics, Algorithms*:

> **Exercise 13.2.1.** Let $\bigr\{ X(t), t\geq 0\bigl\}$ be a stochastic process with independent increments. Show that $\bigr\{X(t), t\geq 0\bigl\}$ is a martingale if $\mathrm{E}\bigl[X(t)- X(s)\bigr] = 0$ for any $s, t \geq 0$ and $\mathrm{Prob}[X(0)=0] = 1$.
>
> **Official solution to 13.1.4:** In fact,
>   \begin{align}\mathrm{E}&\bigl[X(t_n) | X(t_{n-1}), X(t_{n-2}), \dots, X(t_1)\bigr]\\&= \mathrm{E}\bigl[X(t_n) -X(t_{n-1})|X(t_{n-1}), X(t_{n-2}), \dots, X(t_1)\bigr] + X(t_{n-1})\\& = X(t_{n-1})\end{align}
>   where the last equality is true because
>   \begin{align} \mathrm{E}&\bigl[X(t_n) - X(t_{n-1})| X(t_{n-1}, X(t_{n-1}), \dots, X(t_1)\bigr]\\
> &= \mathrm{E}\bigl[X(t_n) - X(t_{n-1})  | X(t_{n-1}) - X(t_{n-2}), \dots, X(t_2) - X(t_1), X(t_1) - X(0)\bigr]\\
> &= \mathrm{E}\bigl[X(t_n) - X(t_{n-1}) ] = 0\,.
> \end{align}

---

Now, the definition of a martingale is a stochastic process $\bigr\{X(t), t\geq 0\bigl\}$ with $\mathrm{E}\bigl[|X(t)|\bigr] < \infty$ and $$\mathrm{E}\bigl[X(t) | X(u), 0 \leq u \leq s\bigr] = X(s)\,.$$

I wonder if strictly speaking, we really proved the martingale property if we just proved it for *any* finite subset of $[0, s]$? Because this is something the official solution seems to presuppose.

It proves the assertion just for arbitrary $\{t_1, \dots, t_{n-1}\}$ and not for the *whole* $[0, t_{n-1}]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $E(X(t)|X(u),0 \leq u \leq s)=X(s)$ is equivalent to the property $EX(t)I_A=EX(s)I_A$ for every $A \in \sigma \{X(u),0 \leq u \leq s\}$.

Now the property proved in the official solution  shows that this holds for all $A \in \bigcup \sigma\{X(t_1),x(t_2),...,X(t_n)\}$ where the union is over all finite collections $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$. This union is an algebra which generates $\sigma \{X(u),0 \leq u \leq s\}$. The proof is now finished using a direct application of Dynkin's $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem.